# how can i sort a nested dictionary by values?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, lambda

> here is a code i have:
> how can i sort myteams based on points and goals ? priority is with points.

```
 myteams={"Spain":{"points":12 , "goals":6} , "germany":{"points":20 , "goals":10} }
```

> the answer has to be like :

```
{"germany":{"points":20 , "goals":10} ,"Spain":{"points":12 , "goals":6} }
```

Comment: Something like `{country: inner for (country, inner) in sorted(myteams.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]["points"], x[1]["goals"]))}`?

Comment: >thanks. ** but we should use```` reverse=True```` at the end of it ! then it will work like a score table**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answer = dict(
    sorted(myteams.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]["points"], x[1]["goals"]), reverse=True)
)
```